# Paypal mobile sdk error 500 with payment

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to use the paypal mobile sdk. I've put my client id, and I test this sample app in sandbox mode. But when I click on the button to pay, the app is loading for about 1 minute and then I have this error in the logcat :

[image: Paypal bug]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I tested with a false credit card number